# most common Turkish words

Tags: resource-request, turkish

I'm trying to learn most common Turkish words but I can't find resources, I've already finished 1000 words. Where do I find the most common Turkish words, at least 10k?

Comment: As a request for a language resource it is on-topic, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

*[A Frequency Dictionary of Turkish](https://www.routledge.com/A-Frequency-Dictionary-of-Turkish/Aksan-Aksan-Mersinli-Demirhan/p/book/9781138839670)* by Yeşim Aksan, Mustafa Aksan, Ümit Mersinli and Umut Ufuk Demirhan (Routledge, 2017) contains the **5,000 most common words** in Turkish, based on a 50 million word corpus. The words are listed by frequency; each has an example sentence. (There is an alphabetical index at the end.)

Answer (score 2):

You can find frequency weighted Turkish word lists at the [Wortschatz pages](http://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de?corpusId=tur_news_2005) of Universtät Leipzig.

Comment: but there isn't a list of most common words sorted, it only contains 1 word look up and their examples.